# onload add class to the document

Tags: onload, addclass

Simply when the page loads I'd like to add a blur to the whole document

```
    function loading() {

    document.getElementById('.header').addClass('loading-style');

    setTimeout(function(){}, 3000);
}
```

and there's `<body onload="loading()">`

And finally the style :

```
.loading-style {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    -o-filter: blur(5px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function loading() {

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('body').addClass('loading-style')
    })

    setTimeout(function(){}, 3000);
}
```

Comment: `setTimeout(function(){}, 3000);` doesn’t do anything here.

Comment: oh ye, bcs i placed the reverse of loading style later on